# How to insert a string between particular characters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

Say I have a large parent string containing many characters. How can I insert another string between a certain match of characters (and additionally, erase any characters already between my matching characters)?

For example, my `largeString` is guaranteed to contain a single set of `######`'s (6 hash characters). How can I insert my `smallString` between it, ending up with something similar to (I guess it would be better to say 'create another string', since strings are immutable):

```
largeString = "Lorem ipsum ###### some previous text to be erased ###### dolor sit amet"
smallString = "foo bar"

newString = "Lorem ipsum ###### foo bar ###### dolor sit amet"
```

Any ideas? I assume this will use a bit of regex...

Comment: are you wanting to replace all occurrences or a single occurrence?

Comment: @Cfreak There will always only be a single occurrence in the larger string.

Comment: if you know what the text you want erased is then you can use a simple `.replace()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
>>> import re
>>> largeString = "Lorem ipsum ###### some previous text to be erased ###### dolor sit amet"
>>> smallString = "foo bar"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=###### ).*(?= ######)', smallString, largeString)
Lorem ipsum ###### foo bar ###### dolor sit amet'
```

- `(?<=###### )` Postive look behind. Asserts that # prescedes the string
- `.*` Matches anything
- `(?= ######)` Postive look ahead. Asserts that # follows the string

**OR**

without look arounds

```
>>> re.sub(r'(###### ).*( ######)', r'\1'+smallString+r'\2', largeString)
'Lorem ipsum ###### foo bar ###### dolor sit amet'
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be 6 hashes rather than three on the trailing character match?

Comment: @Antilogical Does the input string `largeString` contains 6 or 3 hashes?

Comment: It contains a single set of six hashes. So I think your code would need to be amended to: `re.sub(r'(?<=###### ).*(?= ######)', smallString, largeString)`, but I'm not sure I've got the syntax right.

Comment: @Antilogical So i expect there is a typo in the example `largeString` you provided. Will edit my answer

Comment: Ah, there is too. Apologies. I've edited my question to the correct notation. Your answer looks good, I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
sections = largeString.split("######", 2)
newString = sections[0] + smallString + sections[2]
```

Possibly with an assertion in there that checks that `sections` is indeed a list of three elements (i.e. that the two delimiters were found).

Since your delimiter is a static string, there's not really any reason to pull out regular expressions, other than the rampant (but erroneous) "regular expressions can solve anything" mentality that seems to be sweeping the world...

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=######)[^#]+
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wV5tP1/9

```
re.sub(r'(?<=######)[^#]+', smallString, largeString)
```